# Are the space of paths with two given endpoints in a contractible space, contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

This question is inspired by an answer to Nitrogen's answer to my [Are the path connected components of $\Omega S_1$ contractible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645514/are-the-path-connected-components-of-omega-s-1-contractible/1645535#1645535) .

Here we are asked whether the space of paths in $\mathbb{R}$ sending $0$ to $0$, $1$ to $n$, with $[0,n] \subset \mathbb{R}$, is contractible?  The answer is yes because $\mathbb{R}$ is convex, i.e. there is a natural choice of a path(namely a line segment) from the tail endpoint of a path,  to $n$.  In more detail, we have a deformation retract from $P_{0 \to 0} ([0,N])$ of basepoint fixing paths in $[0,N]$ to the space $P_{0 \to 0, 1 \to N} ([0,N])$.  The retraction is given by sending any path $\gamma_a(t)$ with $\gamma_a(t)=x$ to the path $\gamma_b$ that does the line segment from $x$ to $n$ on $[(n-x)/n, 1]$ and a shrinked version of $\gamma_a$ on $[0,(n-x)/n]$.  Thus $P_{0 \to 0} ([0,N])$ which is contractible  is homotopy equivalent to $P_{0 \to 0, 1 \to N} ([0,N])$.

Is the following generalization of this true:  Let $A$ be a contractible topological space and let $x_1$ and $x_2 \in A$ be given.  Is the space of paths with the indicated endpoints $P_{0 \to x_1, 1 \to x_2}(A)$ contractible?

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can assume WLOG that $x_1 = x_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Qiaochu's comment: Suppose $H:A \times I \to A$ is a homotopy from the identity to the constant map on $x_2$. Then $\lambda=H(x_1,-)$ is a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

I claim that $P_{0 \to x_1, 1 \to x_2}(A)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega A$, the based loops at $x_1$, which is contractible. Consider the maps $$f:P_{0 \to x_1, 1 \to x_2}(A) \to \Omega A, \ \ g:\Omega A \to P_{0 \to x_1, 1 \to x_2}(A)$$ given by $f(\alpha)=\alpha \cdot \bar{\lambda}$ and $g(\alpha)=\alpha \cdot \lambda$. With a little bit of techinique, using $H$, you can show that these maps are homotopy inverse to each other.

Comment: You're doing two proofs at once, I think it would be a little bit clearer if you separated the proof of $P_{x_1, x_2}A \simeq \Omega_{x_1} A$ (you don't need the whole homotopy $H$ for this, just a path from $x_2$ to $x_1$), and the proof that $\Omega A$ is contractible if $A$ is contractible.